# Why can't I break an *.Rdata loading process?

Tags: r, import, interrupt, rdata

It seems that R is not responding when trying to break loading an *.Rdata file with `load("*.Rdata")`. What is the reason and is there a way around?

I tried to break several file loading processes with different files and sizes. The only possibility then seems to be to terminate R. I am working with large file sizes whose loading time exceeds half an hour.

[image]

Comment: How large are these things? R is trying to load them into RAM, and 30m should be long enough to load a terabyte into RAM, if you have a terabyte of RAM... which you probably dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're stuck. R doesn't make guarantees about whether low-level processes can be interrupted by the user. Low-level C code needs a call to `R_CheckUserInterrupt()` in order to "notice" a request from the user to break execution (see Wickham's [advanced r book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#clang).  You can see the low-level [code for loading data](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/596fdf2f9679ed3a7744b5d61168759b8944b1c7/src/main/saveload.c) if you like (although it may not be too helpful ...)

The only workaround I can think of (besides making sure that you really do want to load a particular data file) is to find ways to decompose your data into smaller chunks (and concatenate the chunks appropriately after reading them into R). If data reading is a really big bottleneck you could look at the [high-performance computing task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) section on out-of-memory data tools ...